# Modularized App and Global State (Android Compose)

Tags: state, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, jetpack-compose-navigation, modularization

I am following the [Now In Android sample](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) for [modularization](https://developer.android.com/topic/modularization) and best practices with Jetpack Compose and I am a bit stuck with sharing a simple LocalDate state across several modules/features.

I want to be able to change a selected date in several places, and update the UI accordingly in several places (i.e. AppState, BottomSheet (BottomSheetState), Screen A (Viewmodel) / Screen B (Viewmodel), Dialog (if opened), etc.).

Now considering concepts like Ownership and Encapsulation, I am not sure which would be the preferred way to handle this. Or how I should rethink the logic.

---

**So far I tried:**

1. Hoisting the state in AppState and passing it onto Composables below;

   - Problem here was that I cannot pass the stateflow on to the VMs due to DI with hiltViewModel() and Compose Navigation. (Example of implementation:)

```kt
@OptIn(ExperimentalLifecycleComposeApi::class)
@Composable
internal fun ScreenARoute(viewModel: ScreenAViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
ScreenA(/***/)
}
```

```kt
@HiltViewModel
class ScreenAViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userPrefsRepository: UserPrefsRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
/***/
}
```

2. Using SavedStateHolder in ViewModels, including the MainActivityViewmodel where the date should be initialized (today);

   - Problem here was that the state was only updated in the respective VM/SavedStateHolder and not across all places. For example I was able to update the date and state in Screen A and the UI got updated accordingly, other places/screens remained without updates though. (Example of implementation:)

```kt
@HiltViewModel
class ScreenAViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userPrefsRepository: UserPrefsRepository,
    val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {
/***/

    val selectedDate: StateFlow<LocalDate> =
        savedStateHandle.getStateFlow<LocalDate>(SELECTED_DATE_SAVED_STATE_KEY, LocalDate.now())
            .stateIn(
                viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
                initialValue = LocalDate.now()
            )

    fun updateSelectedDate(date: LocalDate) {
        savedStateHandle[SELECTED_DATE_SAVED_STATE_KEY] = newDate
/***/
}
```

---

**Other things I am considering:**

- Creating a Singleton object that holds the state, which is initialized in the MainActivityViewModel and implemented in the VMs via hilt DI.
- Using Room or Preferences to save the state and share across the app per Singleton Repository and DI. But this might be overkill?

---

The state should survive configuration changes but can be disposed when the app gets killed. Any help will be much appreciated.